# different drawables with layer-list for ToggleButton states

Tags: java, android, xml, layer-list

In my app i need to display toggle button that looks like this (this one is for checked state) http://s58.radikal.ru/i159/1308/dc/e3cb45e9a71f.jpg, dark color is parent view background.
It must be just a colored circle with 50x50 size, but for checked state it must include that blue border outside. The whole button must be always 70x70, so it has enough space for border. I guess i have to use simple shape drawable for default state and layer-list drawable for checked state, but it doesnt work for me, it just creates some kind of stretched oval and without any border(like this http://s019.radikal.ru/i619/1308/50/0f02f9ab2ea4.jpg). Here is the code i'm using for ToggleButton background:

**first_board_color_dot.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/first_board_color_dot_checked"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/first_board_color_dot_default"></item>
</selector>
```

**first_board_color_dot_checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="34dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="2dp" >
            <solid android:color="@color/first_player_dot_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" android:gravity="center">
            <solid android:color="@color/first_board_color" />

            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**first_board_color_dot_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" android:gravity="center">
            <solid android:color="@color/first_board_color" />

            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

this is how i'm setting up button

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/board_color_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@drawable/first_board_color_dot"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="boardColorButtonClicked"/>
```

i cannot understand what im doing wrong...